# can not log out my users in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

By logic, once the users logged out, they cann't enter the system again till they login again.
I use some session data and cookies of the logged in users, and i want to delete this session data and cookies when the users logged out.
I use

```
delete_cookie("cookie_name");
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

and also set the `$config['sess_time_to_update']` ro  `0`

but this is didn't work, the session data and cookies didn't deleted.
What i can do to delete all session data and cookies once the user log out.

Comment: If you need to clear the values of $_SESSION, set the array equal to an empty array:

$_SESSION = array();
Of course, you can't access the values of $_SESSION on another page once you call session_destroy, so it doesn't matter that much.

Try the following:

session_destroy();
$_SESSION = array(); // Clears the $_SESSION variable

Comment: but codeigniter doesn't use native php $_SESSION it use cookies insteed.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->sess_destroy();
```

should delete all the session data. How do you know that the session data wasn't deleted. just after sess_destroy(); try to echo one of the session data.

```
echo $this->session->userdata('item_name');
```

same way use echo after deleting a cookie like this-

```
echo get_cookie('cookie_name');
```

I believe, it's the logic of how user keep logged in. You are probably not checking whether the session exists for logged in user. You should check session and cookie for every page(method) the user visit. The best way to do this is to put the checker function in the constructor.

Comment: I'm already checking if the session exists, then the user is logged in. I use a chrome extension named 'edit this cookie' that show the current cookies of a page, after i log out the session and cookies still exists and not deleted. so if i return to any page in the system, he considered me logged in because the session and cookies exists.

Comment: Why don't you try to echo session and cookie value after deleting them. It will help you better to understand the problem. Can you post the code of login and logout script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

```
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php#73484